# how to adaptively change height of div with scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have a page with specified size, scrollbars of body and html are disabled. On the page I have a div for input (with adaptive height) and list of messages.
Input div works as expected: could expand to fit content until max-height is reached then scrollbar appears.
I need to be able to scroll the list below. In order to do so I need to specify top:0 and height style properties, but I don't understand what value do I need to set to height property since it could change.

```
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: 350px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
```

[code on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/flaVnopskRJDxK5p2C1y?p=preview)

as you can see if I scroll list down it is still partially hidden (don't see 'last message' item). What can I do with that?
 Is that possible to solve the issue using css only?

UPD I put this html into chrome extension popup, so it seems that the solution could be more tricky than usual

Comment: Take the `height` off the `body` tag - it's restricting the whole thing depending on auto content of top div - you can't have both - or, you have to have fixed height on top and bottom divs as well as body then they will stay fixed height and the scroll will correct itself

Comment: @DarrenSweeney thank you for answer but unfortunately this solution doesn't work for popup of chrome extension

Comment: You didn't even mention Chrome extension, how can we know this if you don't supply all relevant facts?

Comment: @Darren Sweeny sorry, I was sure that this popup works in the same way as a HTML page in chrome tab, I will add it to my post, I can assure you that there are no any additional things I forgot to mention